# Problems with Glm functions

Tags: c++, glm-math

Why does this code compile

```
    [[nodiscard]] glm::mat4 rotationX(double theta)
    {
        return glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0), static_cast<float>(theta), glm::vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
    }
```

and this one not

```
    [[nodiscard]] glm::mat4 rotationX(double theta)
    {
        return glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0), theta, glm::vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
    }
```

it results in error `C2672 no matching overloaded function found` and
Error `C2782: Template parameter T is ambigous`.
what type should theta be?

Also this code

```
    [[nodiscard]] glm::mat4 shearing(double xy, double xz, double yx, double yz, double zx, double zy)
    {
        auto sh = glm::mat4(1.0);

        sh[1][0] = xy;
        sh[2][0] = xz;
        sh[2][1] = yz;

        sh[0][1] = yx;
        sh[0][2] = zx;
        sh[1][2] = zy;

        return sh;
    }
```

produces the following warning:
`warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'double' to 'T', possible loss of data`

I can't understand what exactly the error is, because everything else seems to work.

PS, I include

```
#include <glm/fwd.hpp>
```

in .hpp and

```
#include <glm/glm.hpp>  
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
```

in .cpp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using [`glm::rotate`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00247.html#gaee9e865eaa9776370996da2940873fd4) with `vec3` and `mat4`, the type of `theta` must be float, because the element type of `mat4` and `vec3` is `float`:

> ```cpp
> typedef mat<4, 4, f32, defaultp> mat4;
>
> typedef vec<3, float, defaultp> vec3;
> ```

The corresponding double precision data types are `damt4` and `dvec3`:

> ```cpp
> typedef mat<4, 4, f64, defaultp> dmat4;
>
> typedef vec<3, f64, defaultp> dvec3;
> ```

The names of the types are the same as for the corresponding GLSL data types ([Data Type (GLSL)](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL))). In glsl, the matrix and vector data types can be constructed from any basic data type.

Answer (score -1):

```
[[nodiscard]] glm::mat4 shearing(double xy, double xz, double yx, double yz, double zx, double zy)
{
    auto sh = glm::mat4(1.0);

    sh[1][0] = xy;
    sh[2][0] = xz;
    sh[2][1] = yz;

    sh[0][1] = yx;
    sh[0][2] = zx;
    sh[1][2] = zy;

    return sh;
}
```